# Run command to mount a CIFS volume on boot on a Raspberry Pi

Tags: command-line, raspberry-pi, cifs

I am trying to make it so as soon as my Raspberry Pi boots up, it runs the command below so I can mount the drive on startup.

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o username="USERNAME",password="PASSWORD",uid=$(id -u),gid=$(id -g) //192.0.0.10/folder /home/pi/Desktop/folder
```

If you know how I can do this or make it so the drive stays mounted permanently, please tell me.

Comment: (1) Why are you not doing this with `/etc/fstab`? (2) What uid and gid do you want to use?  Yours?  If you run the command (as is) at boot, it will get uid=root and gid=root.

Comment: To make what Scott is saying clearer, what you are attempting to do via the `sudo` and `mount` command is traditionally handled by the `fstab` on Linux systems. You should search online to read up on how to do it that way.

Comment: @Scott that could totally be an answer. I for one might need to look this up for... reasons ;p

Comment: @JakeGould could you tell me what I need to look up on google, I have spent hours finding and trying many things with /etc/fstab but they either get me nowhere or don't work. I am creating a program that requires raspberry pis to read and write to files on a Windows PC. I am excellent programmer but I am not familiar with Linux commands. I just need to do this one thing and I can be finished with my project

Comment: @Brandalf While I believe you are frustrated in attempting to understand how to solve this issue, I don’t believe you have spent hours on Google since a simple search for “[fstab gifs smb](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=fstab+CIFS+SMB&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8)” shows me tons of pertinent results.

Comment: @JakeGould gifs??

Comment: @JakeGould I have been looking up the fstab cif smb link that you gave me, I have spent the last 2 hours trying everything in those results, nothing works, I don't know why. The sudo mount command I use works fine, is there a way that I can just make a command run in the terminal on boot instead

Comment: Fstab is how it's done. Show us the line you added to /etc/fstab.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille `//192.0.0.10/Login /home/pi/Desktop/Login cifs x-systemd.automount,noauto,rw,iocharset=utf8,username=USERNAME,password=PASSWORD,uid=osmc,gid=osmc,file_mode=0770,dir_mode=0770,vers=3.02 0 0` I put that at the end of the /etc/fstab file on the 6th line using `sudo nano`. When I type `sudo mount -a` it does nothing.

Comment: That's because of the 'noauto'.  Do you understand the other options you're using?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille Oh my god dude thank you, you're a life saver. I changed it to "auto" and now it works, thank you so much.

Comment: You're welcome but don't exagerate ;-)  I've put it up as an answer, please accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following to /etc/fstab:

```
//192.0.0.10/Login /home/pi/Desktop/Login cifs x-systemd.automount,auto,rw,iocharset=utf8,username=USERNAME,password=PASSWORD,uid=osmc,gid=osmc,file_mode=0770,dir_mode=0770,vers=3.02 0 0
```